# Handling T-SQL Query with null filters as parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, parameters, filter, null

Suppose I have a stored procedure where I'm passing in 5 filters as parameters.  These parameters are filters to each column in my query.  My query has 5 fields.  What is the best way to prevent my query from throwing an exception/error if I have 1 or more NULL (or '') valued parameters for my filters?

```
    SELECT 
        [helpings_turkey],
        [helpings_green_beans],
        [scoops_squash],
        [qty_buscuits],
        [pieces_pie]
    FROM
        [thanksgiving_guest]
    WHERE 
        [helpings_turkey] > @helpings_turkey_filter
        AND [helpings_green_beans] > @helpings_green_beans_filter
        AND [scoops_squash] > @scoops_squash_filter
        AND [qty_buscuits] > @qty_buscuits_filter
        AND [pieces_pie] > @pieces_pie_filter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you won't get an error if the value is null, but you won't get results either.

You could do something like this:

`[helpings_turkey] > ISNULL(@helpings_turkey_filter, X)`

where "X" is something you know to be smaller than your smallest value.

This will work for small datasets, but likely won't be able to take advantage of any indexing you may have on your [thanksgiving_guest] table.

The most performant way of doing filters in patterns like this is to usually to assemble the SQL dynamically, by inserting clauses when non-null filter conditions are encountered like so:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT 
        [helpings_turkey],
        [helpings_green_beans],
        [scoops_squash],
        [qty_buscuits],
        [pieces_pie]
    FROM
        [thanksgiving_guest]
    WHERE 1=1';

IF @helpings_turkey_filter IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + '[helpings_turkey] > @helpings_turkey_filter'
END
...
IF @pieces_pumpkin_pie_filter IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + '[pieces_pumpkin_pie] > @pieces_pumpkin_pie_filter'
END

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@helpings_turkey_filter, ..., @pieces_pumpkin_pie_filter', @helpings_turkey_filter, @pieces_pumpkin_pie_filter`
```

Note that we still continue to parameterize the query even though we are assembling the query dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT 
        [helpings_turkey],
        [helpings_green_beans],
        [scoops_squash],
        [qty_buscuits],
        [pieces_pie]
    FROM
        [thanksgiving_guest]
    WHERE 
        [helpings_turkey] > IsNull(@helpings_turkey_filter, 0)
        AND [helpings_green_beans] > IsNull(@helpings_green_beans_filter, 0)
        AND [scoops_squash] > IsNull(@scoops_squash_filter, 0)
        AND [qty_buscuits] > IsNull(@qty_buscuits_filter, 0)
        AND [pieces_pumpkin_pie] > IsNull(@pieces_pumpkin_pie_filter, 0)
```

Something like this.  Use the parameter if its passed in, if not default to some value.I defaulted to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as this will solve your problem (If you are passing more than one parameters which might be NULL:

```
SELECT 
        [helpings_turkey],
        [helpings_green_beans],
        [scoops_squash],
        [qty_buscuits],
        [pieces_pie]
    FROM
        [thanksgiving_guest]
    WHERE 
        [helpings_turkey] > ISNULL(@helpings_turkey_filter, 0)
        AND [helpings_green_beans] > ISNULL(@helpings_green_beans_filter, 0)
        AND [scoops_squash] > ISNULL(@scoops_squash_filter, 0)
        AND [qty_buscuits] > ISNULL(@qty_buscuits_filter, 0)
        AND [pieces_pumpkin_pie] > ISNULL(@pieces_pumpkin_pie_filter, 0)
```